# MySQL is slow when delete records in large table

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a query like this which takes a really long time to run. The table is around 4 million rows.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE value_was IS NULL OR value_was <= value_now;
```

I'm hoping I could create an index for (value_was, value_now) so I could do something like

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE 
ID1 IN (SELECT ID1 from TABLE where value_was IS NULL) 
OR ID2 IN (SELECT ID2 FROM TABLE WHERE value_was <= value_now);
```

This table doesn't have primary key. It has two composite keys. And I guess I cannot use the same table in subquery, but how do I improve the performance of the first query?

Thanks very much any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Updated:
The db is innoDB

Comment: Is the table stored in `myISAM` or `innoDB` storage engine?

Comment: It's innoDB. I have also updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the way data is stored, as an internal linked list, innoDB tables are inherently slow at huge `DELETE` operations. Changing the storage type to `myISAM` should make the operation an awful lot faster - I've seen 100x improvements in similar situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but as it's a legacy system I cannot change the engine. Is there anyway I could improve the query in innoDB?

Comment: Here http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/77660-speed-innodb-deletes-large-tables a guy suggests increasing key_buffer_size

Comment: This article http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig provides much more in-depth information, but I can't tell how old it is... HTH, anyway :)

Comment: @toy if you can execute queries you should be able to change the engine as well. It's 3 clicks in phpMyAdmin, or a few commands by hand.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani that article is fairly recent, it mentions MySQL 5.1. Anyway, both articles confirm the inherent sluggishness of innoDB on large deletes. Not much you can do about that apart from buying a faster server or switching to myISAM - all the other fixes could increase the speed by 200% or 300%, but nothing stellar.